# Кодировка Java (JSP) and MySQL

Tags: sql, java, mysql

Дело вот в чем. В СУБД MySQL кодировки установлены следущим образом:

```
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | utf8   |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

Далее, есть JSP страница. В ней присутствует meta-аттрибут:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Текст заноситься в БД через формы ввода на странице. После ввода кириллицы в базе вижу что то вроде `ÑÐ·ÐµÑ`

В чем косяк? :) Где что поправить нужно? Уже какие только комбинации не пробовал...
Или может уже в Java коде нужно как-то указывать в какой кодировке мы добавляем новую запись в таблицу?

Код инсерта в таблицу:

```
if (request.getParameter("Add")!=null){
            //  Если поля ввода не пусты
            if (!request.getParameter("firstName").equals("") 
                    && !request.getParameter("lastName").equals("") 
                    && !request.getParameter("birthDate").equals("")) {
                newRequest.Add(request.getParameter("firstName"), request.getParameter("lastName"), request.getParameter("birthDate"));

public static void Add(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) {
        String sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO test.Students (FirstName, LastName, BirthDate) VALUES ('"
                + firstName + "', '"
                + lastName + "', '"
                + birthDate + "');";

        DatabaseRequestExecuter.INSERT(sql);
    }

public static void INSERT (String SQL) {

        Connection connection = DatabaseRequestExecuter.newConnection();
        PreparedStatement myStatement = null;

        try {
            myStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            myStatement.execute();
            connection.close();
            myStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RequestQreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
```

Точнее куски кода, подключение к базе - стандартное из учебника.

Comment: сделайте фильтр меняющий кодировку на request и response на UTF - 8

Comment: А можно ссылочку какую нибудь по теме?

Comment: @VorobyevEvngeniy, с UTF-8 всё правильно, но она распознаётся как [windows-1252](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Да, да, так и есть, воспринимает как 1252, а как бороться с этим? Добавил код инсерта в таблицу

Comment: @VorobyevEvgeniy, `<Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />`?

Comment: [первая ссылка по запросу из гугла по поводу фильтра][1]


  [1]: http://dertompson.com/2007/01/29/encoding-filter-for-java-web-applications/  
  
  
  только не забудьте еще у response изменить.  
И да, тут еще подсказывают сменить кодировку у контейнера сервлетов, не забудьте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, попробуйте начать с БД заново только в консоли (ради чистоты эксперимента).
Во вторых, введите команду SET NAMES cp866.
У меня была точно такая же ситуация, мне помогло.
Правда у вас не написано про настройку томката и соединений в самом проекте.
Для томката в server.xml дописать URIEncoding="UTF-8, пример :

```
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
И в проекте в сервлетах добавить.
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.setContentType ("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Помогло
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

> После ввода кирилици в базе вижу что
> то вроде ÑÐ·ÐµÑ

На чем вы видите? На консоли, который неспособен отображать UTF-8? Очевидно дело в способе отображения.

Comment: Вижу в базе, смотрю через MySQL Workbench

Comment: Java код добавления данных в студию!

Comment: @VorobyevEvgeniy А HTML сгенерированный JSP, который выдается юзеру - какая там кодировка? Посмотрите заголовок что он там вещает юзеру?

Comment: Там UTF-8/